# Juju status error

Tags: juju, maas

I am using MaaS as environment and I have one node as WOL (Wake-On-Lan).

When I do `juju status` I get the following error:

```
ERROR Unable to connect to environment "maas".
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.
```

Error details:

```
unable to connect to "wss://node.maas:17070/"
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you execute "juju bootstrap" without quotes?

Comment: Yes, I did juju bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bootstrap worked, you need to either add the IP for node.maas to /etc/hosts on the machine where you are running "juju status", or change /etc/resolv.conf and include the MAAS IP as a nameserver, assuming you configured MAAS to own DNS too for your node network.